# How to capture an Error Message into a file in DataStage

Tags: datastage

Is it possible to capture the error message/error field into a file in DataStage?

Like if some error occurs in Transformer Stage, then is it possible to capture the error and the field which had the error into a file? As of now, I am able to capture the entire error record into a file but not the error message or just the error field.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no.  Certainly there is no generic solution.  You could create a rejects link from the Transformer stage, but even that is limited in its capability.
I suspect you would be better served reading the error information from the job log, and processing that.